# gulp-rsync on Windows not Making Directory on Remote Linux Server

Tags: javascript, linux, gulp, rsync

I've gotten the following gulp task to transfer files from a Windows 10 machine to a remote Linux server. However, files are being copied with a backslash "\" vice forward slash "/" resulting in long file names like "js\myjs.js" instead of creating a folder called "js" with "myjs.js" in it. I haven't found an option or switch to fix the problem. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
gulp.task('deploy', function() {
  return gulp.src('dist/*/')
   .pipe(rsync({
     options: {
      chmod: 'ugo=rwX',
      'r': true,
      'v': true,
      'delete': true,
      'verbose': true,
      'progress': true
   },
   username: "user",
   password: "pass",
   hostname: 'host.com',
   destination: '~/test/',
   recursive: true,
   clean: true,
   root: "dist/"
  }));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem and the **solution** is described [here](https://github.com/jerrysu/gulp-rsync/issues/33) as follows:

> In gulp-rsync index.js change:

```
  source: sources.map(function(source) {
    return path.relative(cwd, source.path) || '.';
  }),
```

> to:

```
  source: sources.map(function(source) {
    var file_path = (path.relative(cwd, source.path) || '.').replace( /\\/g, '/')
    // console.log( 'gulp-rsync source:', source.path, ', ret: ', file_path );
    return file_path
  }),
```

> path.relative() is the culprit.

### The better solution ..

There is already a [stcruy's fork](https://github.com/stcruy/gulp-rsync.git) of gulp-rsync solving this. To deploy it, do the following:

```
npm remove -D gulp-rsync
npm install -D https://github.com/stcruy/gulp-rsync.git
```